# Why does Mapbox on Android takes a long time to display user Location Dot

Tags: android, mapbox-android

I am investigating the use of Mapbox on Android.

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.7.2'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.24.1'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-localization:0.5.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation:0.3.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-traffic:0.6.0'
```

Everything is working as expected apart from the exceptionally long time it takes for the displayed map to show the device current location dot.

Is there any way to improve this user experience?

heres my Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rest_rooms);

    mapView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    final LocationEngineProvider locationEngineProvider = new LocationEngineProvider(this);
    locationEngine = locationEngineProvider.obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();

}

private void manageLocationEngine() {

    locationEngineListener = new LocationEngineListener() {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        @Override
        public void onConnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected() called");
            locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged() called with: location = [" + location + "]");
            if (mapboxMap != null) {
                mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location), 16));
            }
        }
    };

    locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(locationEngineListener);
}

/**
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})
private void enableLocationComponent() {
    if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
        manageLocationEngine();
        manageLocation();
    } else {
        permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
        permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void manageLocation() {

    final LocationComponentOptions options = LocationComponentOptions.builder(this)
            .trackingGesturesManagement(true)
            .accuracyColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .build();

    final LocationComponent locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
    locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(this, options);
    locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);
    locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
    locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);

    final Location lastLocation = new LocationEngineProvider(this).obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable().getLastLocation();
    if (lastLocation != null) {
        mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lastLocation), 16));
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @param requestCode
 * @param permissions
 * @param grantResults
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

/**
 *
 * @param permissionsToExplain
 */
@Override
public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_explanation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

/**
 *
 * @param granted
 */
@Override
public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
    if (granted) {
        enableLocationComponent();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_not_granted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
    locationEngine.activate();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mapView.onStop();
    locationEngine.removeLocationUpdates();
    locationEngine.deactivate();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
    this.mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(this);
    enableLocationComponent();
}
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by the "exceptionally long time?" For me the user location typically shows within 5 or 6 seconds of the map being initialized.